# How do I compare rows and columns of a 2-D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a 2-D array with random integers stored in each location. My question is that I want to compare each row element with the next two and also each column element with the next two so that no same number is generated 3 times consecutively either in a row or column.
Eg: the array should ideally be like=

```
1 1 2 3 0 2 4 4
3 2 2 1 0 2 1 1
0 0 5 2 0 4 3 2  //no 3 same in rows or columns..
```

And no something like:

```
1 1 2 3 0 4 4 4
3 2 2 1 0 2 1 1
0 0 2 2 0 4 3 2
```

I have written my code which compares the rows of the array first and changes the values if there are any same and then after the rows are done it checks the columns. Now my code works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Here is my code:

```
int array_1[10][15] = { { 0 } }; //creates a new 2-D array with zeros.
for (int row = 0; row<10; row += 1) //puts random values in array in range 0 to 5
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <15; col += 1)  
        {
            array_1[row][col] = rand() % 6;
        }
    }
for (int row = 0; row <8; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <13; col++)
    {
        if (array_1[col][row] == array_1[col][row + 1] && array_1[col][row]== array_1[col][row + 2]) // checks each row for 3 consecutive
        {
            array_1[col+1][row] = rand()%6;
        }
        if (array_1[col+1][row] == array_1[col + 1][row] && array_1[col][row] == array_1[col + 1][row]) // checks each column for 3 consecutive
        {
            array_1[col][row] = rand()%6;
        }
    }
}
```

And please don't use any inbuilt functions from c++, I am trying to do this with only logical and comparison statements.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: Yes..but the debugger doesn't sense any errors since the code does run..just not how I want it to.

Comment: That is not a debugger, that is the compiler.  The debugger is a tool that lets you step through your code and watch how it is executed.  Here is a good read: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @carlson.boy Did you read my comment? I asked have you tried **stepping through** your code with a debugger? Debugger **isn't supposed** to show the errors on its own.

Comment: You need to take care that `rand()%6` should not give same no. i.e. the new no. should not be same to the adjustment+1 row or column.

Answer (score 2):

Your indexing in the nested loop is wrong. When you do `array_1[col][row]` you will go out of bounds when `col` becomes equal or larger than `10`. That of course leads to *undefined behavior*.

I suspect you mean `array_1[row][col]` (like in the initialization loop).

Answer (score 1):

I feel you should split your logic into two parts for simplicity and better checking. 1st part for verifying rows and 2nd for verifying columns. 
Also in your code, you need take care that rand()%6 should not generate same no. again. I have also written logic for the same.
You can check following code.

```
// Loop for row
for(row=0;row<8;row++)
{
    for(col=0;col<13;col++)
    {
        if(array_1[row][col] && array_1[row][col+1] && array_1[row][col+2] )
        {
            // Make sure that rand()%6 should not generate same number
            while(array_1[row][col+1] == array_1[row][col+2])
            {
                array_1[row][col+1] = rand()%6;
            }
        }
    }
}
//Loop for column
for(col=0;col<13;col++)
{
    for(row=0;row<8;row++)
    {
        if(array_1[row][col] && array_1[row+1][col] && array_1[row+2][col] )
        {
            // Make sure that rand()%6 should not generate same number
            while((array_1[row+1][col] == array_1[row+2][col]) && (array_1[row+1][col] == array_1[row+1][col+1]))
            {
                array_1[row+1][col] = rand()%6;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to create a 2D array without any value repeating 3 times consecutively either in a row or in a column.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int array_1[10][15] = { { 0 } }; //creates a new 2-D array with zeros.
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) //puts random values in array in range 0 to 5
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 15; col++)
        {
            array_1[row][col] = rand() % 6;
            if (col > 1 && array_1[row][col - 1] == array_1[row][col - 2])
            {
                while (array_1[row][col] == array_1[row][col - 1])
                {
                    array_1[row][col] = rand() % 6;
                }
            }

            if (row > 1 && array_1[row - 1][col] == array_1[row - 2][col])
            {
                while ((array_1[row][col] == array_1[row - 1][col]) ||
                       (array_1[row][col] == array_1[row][col - 1] && array_1[row][col - 1] == array_1[row][col - 2]))
                {
                    array_1[row][col] = rand() % 6;
                }
            }
            std::cout << array_1[row][col] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```